# Get rows based on the existence of related rows in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, exists

This is what my data looks like. If I do the following query:

```
select * from gdax_trades where order_type='limit' limit 5;
```

I get a return that looks like this:

```
 row_id  |               order_id               |  price  | funds | maker_order_id | taker_order_id | trade_id | product_id |              client_oid              | reason | remaining_size |    size    |  sequence  | side |          time           | order_type | event_type 
---------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+--------+----------------+------------+------------+------+-------------------------+------------+------------
 3697499 | 01d63a5b-a5b7-4153-b93d-bd18c249d9c3 | 4113.06 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | 50028bab-81da-4842-98f0-2a1206669567 |        |                |       0.01 | 7446101470 | buy  | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.047 | limit      | received
 3697501 | 9295111b-2e23-445c-9f52-52d2f26fb418 | 4131.93 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | de58f4a6-4577-4680-b083-df34ade6c001 |        |                | 0.12792387 | 7446101472 | sell | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.071 | limit      | received
 3697504 | 4c09878d-8bf9-49d7-9fc7-ca81b7da9e42 | 4131.19 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | a55e0315-8b65-4525-a7a7-debcf6f17bb5 |        |                | 0.10898271 | 7446101475 | sell | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.155 | limit      | received
 3697506 | 0a157570-a811-420e-81ff-0ead9cc34984 | 4132.69 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | 45086077-34be-441e-947f-99fe60bd88ef |        |                | 0.12146031 | 7446101477 | sell | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.24  | limit      | received
 3697508 | e8e1d02f-e627-4eac-a2e5-61c08399d6ef | 4117.83 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | 00000000-818a-0006-0001-000011037107 |        |                |      0.001 | 7446101479 | sell | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.259 | limit      | received
(5 rows)
```

There are other rows in the table corresponding to each `order_id` but do not have `order_type='limit'`. For example, if I try to find all rows that correspond to the first `order_id`:

```
select * from gdax_trades where order_id='01d63a5b-a5b7-4153-b93d-bd18c249d9c3';
```

I get:

```
 row_id  |               order_id               |  price  | funds | maker_order_id | taker_order_id | trade_id | product_id |              client_oid              |  reason  | remaining_size | size |  sequence  | side |          time           | order_type | event_type 
---------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+--------------------------------------+----------+----------------+------+------------+------+-------------------------+------------+------------
 3697499 | 01d63a5b-a5b7-4153-b93d-bd18c249d9c3 | 4113.06 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    | 50028bab-81da-4842-98f0-2a1206669567 |          |                | 0.01 | 7446101470 | buy  | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.047 | limit      | received
 3697500 | 01d63a5b-a5b7-4153-b93d-bd18c249d9c3 | 4113.06 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    |                                      |          |           0.01 |      | 7446101471 | buy  | 2018-11-29 04:15:39.047 |            | open
 3697662 | 01d63a5b-a5b7-4153-b93d-bd18c249d9c3 | 4113.06 |       |                |                |          | BTC-USD    |                                      | canceled |           0.01 |      | 7446101633 | buy  | 2018-11-29 04:15:40.522 |            | done
(3 rows)
```

What I want is a SQLAlchemy query that returns to me rows with an `order_id` corresponding to a "limit" order. I tried doing a self referential join:

```
GDAXTradeAlias = aliased(GDAXTrade)

orders = (
    sess
    .query(GDAXTrade)
    .filter( GDAXTrade.time.between(start_dt, end_dt) )
    .filter(GDAXTrade.order_type=='limit')
    .join(GDAXTradeAlias, GDAXTrade.order_id==GDAXTradeAlias.order_id)
    .filter( GDAXTrade.time.between(start_dt, end_dt) )
    .all() )
```

but that did not get me the desired result. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Postgres version and table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) would be helpful (while the many unrelated columns in the sample output are not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways possible. I suggest an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join. Probably fastest an very clear to read:

```
SELECT *
FROM   gdax_trades g
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM gdax_trades
   WHERE  order_type = 'limit'
   AND    order_id = g.order_id
   );
```

The `SELECT` list of an `EXISTS` expression can stay empty. Only the *existence* of at least one row is relevant.

We need at least one table alias (`g` in the example) when addressing the same table twice. I did not table-qualify columns referring to the local table inside the subquery, since that is visible first. Only qualified the reference to the outer query as `g.order_id`. This is the minimum requirement to be unambiguous. You can be more explicit if you want.

This *includes* "limit" orders in the result. You can easily exclude them by adding a final:

```
...
WHERE order_type IS DISTINCT FROM 'limit'
```

[`IS DISTINCT FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) because `order_type` seems to be nullable (unclear whether those are `''` or `NULL` in your sample result ). `WHERE order_type <> 'limit'` would exclude rows with `order_type IS NULL`.

The query returns unique rows from the outer table, even if there are multiple "limit" orders with the same `order_id`. Various alternative query techniques with joins or subqueries return duplicates in that case. Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I also posted an answer using a subquery. I'm curious if you think your solution would be more performant?

Comment: `.between(start_dt, end_dt)` aside, there is a functional difference in principle: If your subquery finds more than 1 "limit" order with the same `order_id`, you get duplicates rows from the join, while `EXISTS` returns unique rows - which is also the reason why it's potentially faster: it can stop looking as soon a single row has been found for the same `order_id`. If `order_id` is unique among "limit" orders, there won't be much difference. I would pick `EXISTS` for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using sub queries. I'm curious what people think of this

```
    sub_query = ( 
        sess
        .query(GDAXTrade)
        .filter( GDAXTrade.time.between(start_dt, end_dt) )
        .filter(GDAXTrade.order_type=='limit')
        .subquery() 
        )

    orders = (
        sess
        .query(GDAXTrade)
        .join(sub_query, GDAXTrade.order_id==sub_query.c.order_id, isouter=True)
        .filter(GDAXTrade.order_id==sub_query.c.order_id)
        .filter( GDAXTrade.time.between(start_dt, end_dt) )
        .order_by(GDAXTrade.time.asc())
        .all()
        )
```